# Reload script within loop if timeout python

Tags: python, selenium

I have a script visiting different websites. Sometimes I will time out and the Traceback will throw the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\visitor.py", line 52, in <module>
    wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.Selector, "theSelector")))
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\wait.py", line 80, in until
    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
TimeoutException: Message:
```

How can I identify this error and just tell the script to start from the beginning if this happens? I'm looping through different aspects and this happens within the loop. So I just want to continue from where it crashed. Basically reloading the webpage and executing the commands.

Comment: catch `TimeoutException` and put a `continue` in that except.

Answer (score 0):

This is generic as you haven't provided any example of your code

```
for url in ['http://example.com']:
    try:
        visit_site(url)
    except TimeoutException:
        pass
```

Answer (score 0):

Definitely could help you more with more information (your code!). You also say you want to start the script from the beginning on a timeout, then you say you want to retry from where it timed out. I don't see why you would re-run the script, so I'm going to propose a solution that simply refreshes the webpage and tries again.

I'm going to assume a few things.

First, that you set `driver=webdriver.somebrowser()` 
Second, that you set `wait=WebDriverWait(driver, numberseconds)`

I think something like this might work, although could result in endless loop if the page never loads.

`while True: #Could cause endless loop
    try:
        wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.Selector,"theSelector")))
    except TimeoutException:
        driver.refresh()
        continue`

First time ever answering a question!